# JDBC driver with TOMCAT JSP

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, path

I'm beginner in web programming I have a simple question about jdbc drivers.

Where can I place it, in server lib (tomcat/lib), or in WEB-INF/lib? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose either.

The benefits of putting it in tomcat/lib is that the driver is available for all applications deployed to your Tomcat instance, and that you can configure datasources in the Tomcat server configuration. The downside is that the deployed application is dependent on the server configuration: if you replace the server, you will need to be sure to include those additional dependencies.

The benefits of putting it in WEB-INF/lib is that the application is self-contained (it contains all its required libraries), and the dependency is explicitly arranged when building your WAR. The downside is that it can cause memory leaks. For example if the driver is registered with `DriverManager`, but not unregistered on undeploy of the application (although Tomcat has a protection against that). Similar memory leaks can also occur if the driver starts threads but fails to stop them when the web application stops.

Either choice is fine, but in my experience, having the driver in `WEB-INF/lib` is more common (but this is probably a result of the environment I work in).